# Get data value from array

Tags: php

I want to get data value from array. I've tried this code but won't work. It says

```
Notice: Undefined index: s_date
```

This is my code :

```
if($data1['level'] == 'sales')
{
    $dataa[$data1['id_transaksi']]['s_date'] = $data1['inputtime'];
}
else if($data1['level'] == 'sales_admin')
{
    $dataa[$data1['id_transaksi']]['sa_date'] = $data1['inputtime'];
}
else if($data1['level'] == 'teknik')
{
   $dataa[$data1['id_transaksi']]['st_date'] = $data1['inputtime'];
}


foreach($dataa as $datab)
{
   $sd  = $dataa['s_date'];
   $sad = $dataa['sa_date'];
   $std = $dataa['st_date'];
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks before

Comment: what line of code does the notice refers? make sure your `s_date` receives a value, thats what the `Notice` means

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of your conditions are satisified in your if condition, `s_date`, `sa_date` or `st_date` never get set.

```
// If this is true, sa_date and st_date never get set
if($data1['level'] == 'sales') {
    $dataa[$data1['id_transaksi']]['s_date'] = $data1['inputtime'];
}
// If this is true, s_date and st_date never get set
else if($data1['level'] == 'sales_admin') {
    $dataa[$data1['id_transaksi']]['sa_date'] = $data1['inputtime'];
}
// If this is true, s_date and sa_date never get set
else if($data1['level'] == 'teknik') {
   $dataa[$data1['id_transaksi']]['st_date'] = $data1['inputtime'];
}
```

I have a feeling this is what you might want to do:

```
$transaksiId = $data1['id_transaksi'];
$array = array(
    's_date'  => 'sales',
    'sa_date' => 'sales_admin',
    'st_date' => 'teknik',
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $dataa[$transaksiId][$key] = $data1['level'] == $value ? $data1['inputtime'] : null;
}
```

You should also check if the keys are set inside your foreach loop using isset() as demonstrated below. You've also built a 2-d array there. So change the inside of your foreach loop to reference `$datab`

```
foreach($dataa as $datab) {
    $sd  = isset($datab['s_date']) ? $datab['s_date'] : '';
    $sad = isset($datab['sa_date']) ? $datab['sa_date'] : '';
    $std = isset($datab['st_date']) ? $datab['st_date'] : '';
}
```

Comment: It works, but I still have an error in it. Notice: Undefined offset: , why that error appear?

Comment: Because of your `if` loop. If one of those condition is valid, the other two keys will never get set. You need to give them a default value or check if they're set in your foreach loop. I've updated my answer to show you.

Comment: I just realize something. I only had 2 dates on my table, it should be 3 dates. That's why it won't work. Thanks antony :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sd = $dataa['s_date'];
```

is not defined... Take this example:

```
$Array = array(
  array(
    "s_data" => "Example",
    "st_date" => "another example"
  ),
  array(
    "s_data" => "Example",
    "st_date" => "another example"
  )
);
```

then to run through that array:

```
 foreach ($Array AS $Values){
  $sd = $Values['s_data'];
  }
```

You are iterating the array as it's own variable so `$Array['s_data'];` is not defined because you want to pull a non-existant key from the first layer of a multi dimensional array... So iterate as `$Values` inside a foreach